# DELETE in Execute SQL Command Control

Tags: ssis

My Source and Destination tables are on different Servers and they have same schema. I need to merge them in a way that if some record only exists in Target and Does not exist in Source then it should deleted from Destination. How Can i achieve this in SSIS.

Comment: `Execute sql command` component is present in `Control Flow` not `Data Flow ` ? Do you mean `Oledb Command` component ?

Comment: Sorry, Yes i meant OleDb command

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

1.Drag an `Oledb command` and specify the Connection in `connection Manager`  in the dialog box.

2.In the component properties write the sql command to delete the rows

```
 Delete from yourTable
 where id = ?
```

3.In the column mappings tab map `?` with the Input column `ID` coming from the previous component

`Update 2` : Use Lookup after the Oledb Source .Configure the Lookup

Step 1: Select the cache mode .Generally full Cache is selected if the number of rows is less

Step 2:Specify `Redirect rows to no match output`

step 3:Specify the connection and write a query to get Id's(or the joining column ) from the destination table

```
 Select ID from Destination
```

step 4: Macth the `ID` from source with the ID from the destination table and select checkbox for the `Id` column in RHS.

step 5: Follow the Steps written before `Update` for configuring `oledb command` to delete the rows.Make sure you select ID from the `Lookup` not from the `Source` while mapping the `OLEDB command` component